# Что не так со словом "исхаживавшего"?

Tags: словообразование, общие-вопросы

Ввёл в поиск такое слово. Количество результатов удивило. Всего 103! Кажется, что слово составлено грамматически правильно. Смысл его понятен. Каких-то правил, препятствующих его употреблению, тоже не знаю. Так что, получается, слово просто редкое? Или действительно есть причины, почему его нет в словарях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово образовано *корректным* способом и даже присутствует в одном словаре (Словарь синонимов, В.Н. Тришин, 2013) — естественно, в именительном падеже, но малоупотребительно по причине редкости подходящего контекста. В отличие от причастия совершенного вида *исходивший* (напр. всю землю вдоль и поперек), трудно себе представить персонаж, который, "исходив" что-либо, принялся многократно повторять действие "исхаживания" над чем-то ещё (тогда о нём так говорили бы в прошедшем времени) — именно такой смысл можно приписать слову "исхаживавший". Редкий автор стал бы описывать повадки этакого настойчивого шопоголика, систематически **исхаживавшего** в прошлом обширные базары в поисках коллекционного материала. Поэтому неудивительно, что если в именительном падеже это слово ещё можно встретить в каком-то словаре, то в косвенном падеже оно почти не встречается.